# Regex to find numbers from String with different format

Tags: regex, regex-group

I've got the following text:

```
instance=hostname1, topic="AB_CD_EF_12345_ZY_XW_001_000001"
instance=hostname2, topic="AB_CD_EF_1345_ZY_XW_001_00001"
instance=hostname1, topic="AB_CD_EF_1235_ZY_XW_001_000001"
instance=hostname2, topic="AB_CD_EF_GH_4567_ZY_XW_01_000001"
instance=hostname1, topic="AB_CD_EF_35678_ZY_XW_001_00001"
instance=hostname2, topic="AB_CD_EF_56789_ZY_XW_001_000001"
```

I would like to capture numbers from the sample above. I've tried to do so with the regular expressions below and they work well as separate queries:

```
Regex: *.topic="AB_CD_EF_([^_]+).*    
Matches: 12345 1345 1235

Regex: *.topic="AB_CD_EF_GH_([^_]+).*
Matches: 4567 35678 56789
```

But I need a regex which can give me all numbers, ie:

```
12345 1345 1235 4567 35678 56789
```

Comment: From your description, it seems that your input is splitted into multiple lines? I have edited accordingly but in case it is not, please voice out and we can revert it back

Comment: You are not giving clear requirement nor the problem you are facing: can it be simply be "finding number between `"_EF_" / "_GH" ` and `_ZY` ?  That could be done by `/.*(?:_EF_|_GH_)(\d+)_ZY.*/`

Comment: How about `(?<=EF_)(\d+)(?=_ZY)`, Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vbLN9L/6/

Answer (score 2):

Make `GH_` optional:

```
.*topic="AB_CD_EF_(GH_)?([^_]+).*
```

which matches all your target numbers.

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/uLHsQEaq7DiPLJ).

---

You could be more general by allowing *any number* of "letter letter underscore" sequences using:

```
.*topic="(?:[A-Z]{2}_)+([^_]+).*
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/8vJYRRj6b7CZ8s).

Answer (score 1):

Another option that we might call, would be an expression similar to:

```
topic=".*?[A-Z]_([0-9]+)_.*?"
```

and our desired digits are in this capturing group `([0-9]+)`.

[Please see the demo for additional explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/tXrLFi/1/)

Comment: Hi Bohemian, 

Thank you for sharing the link , it helped . I am using the regex in grafana and regex was different there . The link helped me a lot . 

Hi Emma, thank you for the pointer it worked . 
And rest of the folks , all your solutions were working on regex browser but was facing issue in Grafana, because it accepts only first grouping . 

but with all your help, was able to find the right regex . 

cheers

Answer (score 0):

From the examples and conditions you've given I think you're going to need a very restrictive regex, but this may depend on how you want to adapt it. Take a look at the following regex and read the breakdown for more information on what it does. Use the first group *(there is only one in this regex)* as a substitution to retrieve the numbers you are looking for.

**Regex**

```
^instance\=hostname[0-9]+\,\s*topic\=\“[A-Z_]+([0-9]+)_[A-Z_]+[0-9_]+\”$
```

Try it out in this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/GWxNPE/1).

**Breakdown**

```
^                # Asserts position at start of the line
hostname[0-9]+   # Matches any and all hostname numbers
\s*              # Matches whitespace characters (between 0 and unlimited times)
[A-Z_]+          # Matches any upper-case letter or underscore (between 1 and unlimited times)
([0-9]+)         # This captures the number you want
$                # Asserts position at end of the line
```

Although this does answer the question you have asked I fear this might not be exactly what you're looking for but without further information this is the best I can give you. In any case after you've studied the breakdown and played around the demo a it it should prove to be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

The regex worked for me :

```
/.*topic="(?:[AB_CD_EF_(GH_)]{2,3}_)+([^_]]+).*/
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer so as to mark the question as being answered. Read more about why this is encouraged in this blog post named [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).